# .htaccess : wrong redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This is my htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# MON COMPTE
RewriteRule ^mon-compte/connexion/?$ mon-compte-login.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mon-compte/mes-informations/?$ mon-compte.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mon-compte/mes-points-de-fidelite/?$ mon-compte-pts.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mon-compte/mes-commandes/?$ mon-compte-commandes.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mon-compte/mes-identifiants/?$ mon-compte-modif-identifiants.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mon-compte/deconnexion/?$ mon-compte-deconnexion.php [L,QSA]
```

BUT...
When i click on a link with, for example, href="[...]/mon-compte/mes-commandes", my browser open "mon-compte/mes-commandes" but display mon-compte.php... and it is the same problem with all my "mon-compte" links... Every links display "mon-compte.php".

Thanks for helping... :(

Comment: The .htaccess redirections seem correct. Are you sure that your php files aren't redirecting to that page?

Comment: This is likely not due to your actual rules, but because of the overlap between the fake path, and the name of a physically existing file - disable `MultiViews`, that should fix it.

Comment: @CBroe: it seems you're right. THANKS. It's strange that htaccess don't understand this...
Other question: now, "mon-compte/mes-commandes" try to open "mon-compte/mon-compte-commandes.php"... why it take the fake path...??

Comment: I’m guessing you got more in your .htaccess, than you have shown us so far?

Comment: No, for my tests, i show us all my htAccess.
Finally, i change paths (no more subfolders) and filenames to avoid overlap. :(
I haven't any more time and i don't understand why it is so complicated while it seems so simple :(